# How to show content / blocks in views for path component 3, 2 OR 1?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

The taxonomy contains mostly 3 levels, sometimes two levels only.

```
Parent
  Child 1
    Grandchild 1
  Child 2
```

Via path alias, the patterns create URLs like:

```
/parent/child1/grandchild1
/parent/child2
```

When I configure my views block with the logic for the grandchild and place this blog into the layout builder of the taxonomy, it's working like a charm.
[image]

Only when I hit the the URL of the child (not grandchild) I get the error:

```
Drupal\Core\Database\InvalidQueryException: Query condition 'taxonomy_term_field_data.name IN ()' cannot be empty. in Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Condition->condition() (line 117 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Query/Condition.php).
```

(which seems to make sense, since there is not 3rd component in my path - `/parent/child2`)

How to "catch" the request without a 3rd component or how can I validate either component 3 or 2 (and I'd need 1 as well in some cases).

Comment: The easiest way is just to have 2 blocks within your view. 1 looking for arg3 and 1 looking for arg 2

Comment: That would be fine. Issue is just the error.
How to make sure, if there is no arg3, then I'd only show results for arg2?

Comment: Settings for the contextual filter already give you that option. What did you choose below the Specify validation criteria? Do you have **2** Contextual filters, one for child, another for grandchild, in correct order, and with correct Relationships?

Comment: I couldn't get it working via the path. Now I'm using `Content: Has taxonomy term ID` as a contextual filter and it works directly for all depths and even with special characters.